# Counting number of elements in a list that satisfy the given predicate

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Does Haskell standard library have a function that given a list and a predicate, returns the number of elements satisfying that predicate? Something like with type `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Int`. My hoogle search didn't return anything interesting. Currently I am using `length . filter pred`, which I don't find to be a particularly elegant solution. My use case seems to be common enough to have a better library solution that that. Is that the case or is my premonition wrong?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The `length . filter p` implementation isn't nearly as bad as you suggest.  In particular, it has only constant overhead in memory and speed, so yeah.

For things that use stream fusion, like the `vector` package, `length . filter p` will actually be optimized so as to avoid creating an intermediate vector.  Lists, however, use what's called `foldr/build` fusion at the moment, which is not quite smart enough to optimize `length . filter p` without creating linearly large thunks that risk stack overflows.

For details on stream fusion, see [this paper](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.104.7401).  As I understand it, the reason that stream fusion is not currently used in the main Haskell libraries is that (as described in the paper) about 5% of programs perform dramatically *worse* when implemented on top of stream-based libraries, while `foldr/build` optimizations can never (AFAIK) make performance actively worse.

Comment: This is really one of the coolest things about Haskell: that you can specify rewrite rules in your own code that get used by the optimizer, and use them to get awesomely composable and efficient code.

Comment: But the point is, you shouldn't write your own code for this: you should just use `length . filter p`, and trust in the optimizer.

Comment: I'd add `count pred = length . filter pred` to my utils.

Comment: That works too...but a word of advice: you'll get better results if you use an `{-# INLINE count #-}` pragma above your declaration of `count`.  (Where "better results" refers to "the optimizer getting more opportunities to do its thing.")

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of that pragma either. I suggest you add that to your answer too.

Comment: Um.  Will someone else besides me confirm that this is actually correct? I'm no longer sure that length is built with foldr to trigger fusion like this.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Fusion happens when a "good consumer" consumes the result of a "good producer". Both are listed [here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.2/html/users_guide/rewrite-rules.html#id570014), and `length` is not included. See also: [GHC #876: length is not a good consumer](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/876).

Comment: (@missingfaktor: you'll need to unaccept this answer before I can delete it.  Bleahhhhh.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman, I don't think you should delete this answer. Just strike the inaccurate bits. That's the convention.

Comment: Updated with a good amount of detail on why this doesn't work, and some ways in which it does work (i.e. the `vector` package).

Answer (score 7):

No, there is no predefined function that does this, but I would say that `length . filter pred` is, in fact, an elegant implementation; it's as close as you can get to expressing what you mean without just invoking the concept directly, which you can't do if you're defining it.

The only alternatives would be a recursive function or a fold, which IMO would be less elegant, but if you really want to:

```
foo :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Int
foo p = foldl' (\n x -> if p x then n+1 else n) 0
```

This is basically just inlining `length` into the definition. As for naming, I would suggest `count` (or perhaps `countBy`, since `count` is a reasonable variable name).

Comment: +1, It appears then I'll have to define a new function in my utils. Thanks for confirming, and for the advice regarding the name of the function.

Comment: I would advise against defining a new function in your utils.  `length . filter pred` will be more legible.  If you're finding yourself repeating it over and over, it's appropriate to define it in a relatively narrow scope (e.g., a `where` binding or an unexported top-level function).  But if you put it in an utils module, third parties reading your code will have to dig that up to figure out what your code is doing.

Answer (score 6):

Haskell is a high-level language. Rather than provide one function for every possible combination of circumstances you might ever encounter, it provides you with a smallish set of functions that cover all of the basics, and you then glue these together as required to solve whatever problem is currently at hand.

In terms of simplicity and conciseness, this is as elegant as it gets. So yes, `length . filter pred` is *absolutely* the standard solution. As another example, consider `elem`, which (as you may know) tells you whether a given item is present in a list. The standard reference implementation for this is actually

```
elem :: Eq x => x -> [x] -> Bool
elem x = foldr (||) False . map (x ==)
```

In order words, compare every element in the list to the target element, creating a new list of Bools. Then fold the logical-OR function over this new list.

If this seems inefficient, try not to worry about it. In particular,

1. The compiler can often optimise away temporary data structures created by code like this. (Remember, this is *the standard way* to write code in Haskell, so the compiler is tuned to deal with it.)
2. Even if it can't be optimised away, laziness often makes such code fairly efficient anyway.

(In this specific example, the OR function will terminate the loop as soon as a match is seen - just like what would happen if you hand-coded it yourself.)

As a general rule, write code by gluing together pre-existing functions. Change this only if performance isn't good enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, +1. I have been using functional programming for long enough, and am well aware of the things you said in your answer, but when I have a pattern as repetitive as the one being discussed here, I factor it out in a separate function.

Comment: [Here](http://goo.gl/jAOMv) is a philosophy page of Factor programming language, a language where composition is _the_ way of doing things, and most code is written in point-free manner. Have a look at it. Many of those guidelines apply regardless of the language, and I happen to follow them. You'll find similar advice in Leo Brodie's "Thinking Forth", which is a great book on software development in general.

Comment: `a smallish set of functions that cover all of the basics, and you then glue these together as required to solve whatever problem is currently at hand` in my book this is the definition of low level

Answer (score 3):

This is my amateurish solution to a similar problem. Count the number of negative integers in a list l

```
nOfNeg l = length(filter (<0) l)
main = print(nOfNeg [0,-1,-2,1,2,3,4] ) --2
```

Answer (score 0):

## No, there isn't!

As of 2020, there is indeed no such idiom in the Haskell standard library yet!  One could (and should) however insert an idiom `howMany` (resembling good old `any`)

```hs
howMany p xs = sum [ 1 | x <- xs, p x ]
-- howMany=(length.).filter

main = print $ howMany (/=0) [0..9]
```

[Try howMany=(length.).filter](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PyO/3Dcxr9JWIyc1L70kQ09TLy0zpyS1iCs3MTPPtqAoM69EBapGQ9/WQDPaQE/PMvb/fwA)

Comment: As I said on your other recent answer, this isn't Code Golf. Also, the asker mentioned in the question that they already know how to do it with `length` and `filter`.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica, length.filter p did not have the requested type signature (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Int but merely [a] -> Int, but you may be right that i should expand my answer that this howMany idiom could indeed be added to the library?

Comment: No, but `\p -> length . filter p` does.

Comment: i know. just like \p->\xs->sum[1|x<-xs,p x] does.(length.).filter still is the shortest and worthy of an even shorter mnemonic.

Comment: I repeat: this isn't Code Golf! Here, we want more understandable answers rather than shorter answers.

Comment: No, it still looks like Code Golf. Lose the TIO link and add some whitespace to the code and it will be better, though.

Answer (score -1):

I'd do manually

```
howmany :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Int 
howmany _ [ ] = 0
howmany pred (x:xs)  = if pred x then 1 + howmany pred xs 
                       else               howmany pred xs
```