# Counting non zero elements in a list in haskell

Tags: haskell

I need to iterate through a list of integers and determine how many non zero elements there are and return those elements. I am not sure if I should use a counter variable as I iterate through the list, and I am interested in the most efficient way to iterate through the list itself. Here is what I have so far... i am new to haskell so I am writing some of this in pseudocode.

```
nonzero :: [int] -> Int
nonzero let counter = 0
if xs == 0 counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: The approach you are trying to use is suitable for an imperative language (e.g. JavaScript or C#), but it is not the right way to do this using Haskell. Do you know about recursion yet? If so, you should write this as a recursive function. If not, I _highly_ recommend that you should read about recursion before solving this problem.

Comment: Check out [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions) for a quick primer on functions, including examples that iterate over lists to e.g. find their length or the sum of their elements

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting number of elements in a list that satisfy the given predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070570/counting-number-of-elements-in-a-list-that-satisfy-the-given-predicate)

Answer (score 7):

**Preamble**

You should pick up a tutorial or five on Haskell.  Learning a language via stackoverflow questions is going to be slow and frustrating.

**Comments**

**Type Signature and Type Variables**

```
nonzero :: [int] -> Int
```

This is a type signature saying that `nonzero` is a function from a list of `int` to an value of type `Int`.

- `int` with a lower-case `i` is a type variable and means the function works over lists of values of any type what-so-ever.

You probably wanted `nonzero :: [Int] -> Int`

**Function declarations**

```
nonzero let counter = 0
```

Nonzero is a function and should be declared as `<function> <args...> = <expression>`.  So that would be:

```
nonzero xs = ...
```

**Function body and immutability**

The body of `nonzero` is an expression of type `Int`.  In Haskell the variables are immutable. Saying `counter = counter + 1` makes no more sense than it would in first grade math - your mental reaction should be "nuh-uh!".  Instead think recursively in terms of base case and inductive step:

```
case xs of
   [] ->  -- Base case, what is the desired value when
          -- the list is empty?  `counter=0` right!
          0 -- In other words, nonzero [] ~ 0
    x:rest -> -- Inductive case.
              -- What do we do with an element?
              -- Compare with zero and...
         if x == 0
            then 1 + nonzero rest -- Add one to the answer
            else nonzero rest     -- Or don't add one if not
```

**Progression**

There are many different ways to write this function that get more or less fancy, more or less concise.  Whenever you write a recursive function you're probably writing a form of **fold** or **map** over a list or other structure.  Instead of manually looping over something there are lots of built-in functions to do this for you.

For example, determine if a value is a zero and emit a 1 if so or a 0 if not then sum the results:

```
nonzero xs = sum (map oneForZero xs)
oneForZero 0 = 1
oneForZero _anyOtherValue = 0
```

Notice the `sum` function is one of these "folds" over the list of Ints that is specifically performing addition.  We could do this manually instead:

```
nonzero xs = foldr accumulate 0 xs
accumulate 0 acc = acc + 1
accumulate _ acc = acc + 0
```

Comment: Or `nonzero = length . filter (/= 0)`.

Comment: Yes, but if you're trying to explain concepts that causes New topics of partial application, lambdas, and composition while giving no or weak motivation to discuss generalizations like folds.

Answer (score -1):

## countNonzeroes xs=sum[1|x<-xs,x/=0]

```hs
countNonzeroes xs=sum[1|x<-xs,x/=0]
main=print$countNonzeroes[0..9]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/Pzm/NK/ELz@vKrUoP7VYoaLYtrg0N9qwpsJGt6JYp0Lf1iCWKzcxM8@2oCgzr0QFVXm0gZ6eZez//wA)

### howMany=(length.).filter

```hs
howMany=(length.).filter
main=print$howMany(/=0)[0..9]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PyO/3Dcxr9JWIyc1L70kQ09TLy0zpyS1iCs3MTPPtqAoM69EBapGQ9/WQDPaQE/PMvb/fwA)

Comment: This isn't Code Golf, and you should know that, since you're active there. (And even if it were, those are hideously ungolfed, so this would be a bad answer even if you were there.)

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica, i did not codegolf here, i aimed to compile OP's + 1 ansatz!